# Select Sender's Name / Number [Transaction/Promotional] From Inbox In Android

Tags: android, sms, message, messaging

I have made an application in android which receives the message and shows in toast. In addition it will forward the same message to selected number.

I have added the functionality that.. If the message receives from particular number(entered in EditText) then and only then it will send to selected number.

Now I want that application will send Transnational/Promotional message when it arrives and forward to selected number.

If anyone help me in this scenario.. I want to select sender's name [eg. VM-XXXX] from inbox...
I can open inbox within my app but cannot select the sender...

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem and I found out that my app doesn't have permission to read "SERVICE SMS" which can be turned on in app settings. [image]

After turning on that, I'm able to receive service SMS. I don't know how to gain permission to read service sms programmatically as of now, but will find out and will post here.

Comment: Okay! I got your point.. What I found in my case that.. It was occurred due to MIUI (UI specially for Xiaomi Phone Users).

Comment: Same code I tried in normal Android UI it works perfectly and got the desired result !  Btw..Thanks for the suggestion !

Comment: If any one can help me out, I am able to get my inbox but i am not able to get my contacts. It shows only Mobile number. Help me !